# Google Maps Geolocation API for China

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api, geolocation, great-firewall-of-china

I am using Google Maps Geolocation API to get location address in china with the help of MCC, MNC, Lac Id and Cell Id.

But Api returns "Not Found" error for all the sets of MCC, MNC, Lac Id and Cell Id of China.

So, is there an issue with Google Api or some other issue?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Since March 2 2011, China started to block Google HTTPS Server periodically.

The 443 port on Google server was blocked for 15 minutes and available for another 15 minutes as a cycle.

You can try to use http servers instead of https to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Google Map work was not very good in China.

So i recommend you use **Baidu Map** instead of Google Map